# How to check for RTTI on all compilers at compile time?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to check for RTTI on all compilers at compile time?

I know on MSVC that there is a compile definition I can check for.

"When /GR is on, the compiler defines the _CPPRTTI preprocessor macro. By default, /GR is on. /GR- disables run-time type information." - Microsoft Documentation

However is there a better way to detect this at compile time?

EDIT:

I'd also settle for a complete list of things I can check for on each compiler.

Comment: Disabling RTTI is compiler specific, so solution to check it is also compiler specific...

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/

Comment: It's also compiler-specific what part of RTTI exactly would be disabled. For instance, can you still `#include <typeinfo>` or is that an error? The Standard says nothing about these things. You can't really do anything useful with that information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the macro `BOOST_NO_RTTI`, that is defined by `boost/config.hpp` if the RTTI support is not available:

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>

#ifdef BOOST_NO_RTTI
#error no rtti
#endif
```

However there is no magic: it is implemented looking for compiler specific macros like `_CPPRTTI` on Visual Studio and `__GXX_RTTI` on GCC.

**Boost.Config** is plenty of macros like that: you should really have a look at [its documetation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html).